# Cesium - Applying color filter to ImageryLayer

Tags: cesiumjs

Has anyone attempted to do this? As far as I can tell from the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a built in function for achieving this. Does anyone know if this is possible? Is it, possibly, a feature that the authors might intend to add to the platform?

Comment: The [documentation](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ImageryLayer.html) shows brightness/contrast/hue/saturation/gamma.  Are you looking for more custom effects?  Would you want to write your own shader, or just looking for more controls?

Comment: Specifically, I was looking for simplistic imagery layers, ranging from a minimalist map to nothing more than an empty globe with a light grey colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ImageryLayer documentation](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ImageryLayer.html) shows how to control brightness, contrast, hue, saturation, and gamma correction.

To get a globe with a solid color, you can remove the imagery layers like so:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    baseLayerPicker: false
});

var globe = viewer.scene.globe;
globe.imageryLayers.removeAll();
globe.baseColor = Cesium.Color.LIGHTSLATEGRAY;
```

A "minimalist map" (as you mention in the comments) is something you would probably need to get from a custom imagery provider.  You may want to check out [Stamen Maps](http://maps.stamen.com/#toner) for some examples of this.  In particular, note their "Toner" map comes in a number of sub-varieties, any of which can be selected in Cesium.

For example, to try the "Toner Background" version, you would use:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    baseLayerPicker: false,
    imageryProvider: Cesium.createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
        url : 'https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-background/',
        credit : 'Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under CC BY SA.'
    })
});
```

**EDIT:** @EmmanuelBuckski (OP) took this idea and ran with it, mixing the above two techniques together to produce a result that looks really nice!  Check it out:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    baseLayerPicker: false
});

var globe = viewer.scene.globe;
globe.imageryLayers.removeAll();
globe.baseColor = Cesium.Color.fromCssColorString('#f3f3f3');

var tonerLayer = globe.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(
    Cesium.createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
        url : 'https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-background/',
        credit : 'Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under CC BY SA.'
    })
);
tonerLayer.alpha = 0.1;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this helps very much. I found a good configuration to work from with the following:

var globe = viewer.scene.globe;
globe.imageryLayers.removeAll();
globe.baseColor = Cesium.Color.fromCssColorString('#f3f3f3');

var tonerLayer = layers.addImageryProvider(Cesium.createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
    url : 'https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-background/',
    credit : 'Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under CC BY SA.'
}));
tonerLayer.alpha = 0.1;


Hopefully that code is legible as a comment!

Comment: That looks awesome!  I copied the code from the comment into the body of the answer, so it would be readable and usable by others.